# Salesforce Household Data Model

Tags: soql, data-model, health-cloud

My company is using Salesforce Health Cloud. We are trying to understand how the Household

Below is an image of the visualforce page that loads with the Household model:

[image]

I am trying to understand how Salesforce is indicating that this is a "Household". This is important to us because not all accounts can be submitted as households. So being able to understand what is linking the record as a "Household" will be important for inserting validation rules.

I am currently querying the database for the following to try and understand the linkage:

```
select Account_Name__c, AccountId, ContactId, CreatedDate, HealthCloudGA__Primary__c, HealthCloudGA__PrimaryGroup__c, HealthCloudGA__Rollups__c, Id, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsDirect, Relationship_Strength__c, Roles, StartDate  from AccountContactRelation
```

When I query the database, there is no field value that indicates the linkage of a "Household".

How are they linking Households in the backend?

Comment: Have you checked the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/health-cloud-data-models/take-a-look-at-the-household-data-model) and also the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_data_model_hh.htm)?

Comment: Check the `Account` record type instead of relationship, that is what the help advises on how to identify housholds: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_data_model_hh.htm

Comment: Turns out its a custom metadata setting that facilitates the groupings...

Answer (score 3):

A `household` is simply a Person Account (It assumes you are not using individual model) of record type Household.

The contacts and Accounts are then linked to it using Account Contact Relationships or Account Account relationships or Contact and Contact relationships!

There is a role field on the Person Account where you select the role of the account contact relationship you are adding!

This is clearly explained in the trailhead [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/health-cloud-data-models/take-a-look-at-the-household-data-model) and also via the Health Cloud administrator guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_data_model_hh.htm).

The group mapper is a custom metadata mappings shown here(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_config_custom_record_type.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its the custom metadata setting that facilitates the groupings.

Comment: For clarity it is this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_config_custom_record_type.htm

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the Household grouping of relationships is a standard Business Account used to group Account-Contact relationships under one roof on the Household Map page for the Patient. HC provides the 'Household' Record type for this purpose. The role assigned to the member that is being added to the household, is a picklist on the Account-Contact relationship junction object.

Other relationships are displayed on the Household Map page under different groupings depending on their relationship type. Eg. Related Accounts; Related Contacts; Care Plan teams.

Care plan teams are special in that they group Case Teams that the patient is a member, with the other members, made up of internal users and external people (Customer Users, Contacts, Person Accounts).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/190536)